# Building XGBoost on SageMaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run XGBoost on AWS Sagemaker and trying to call the container for XGBoost.

```
containers = {'us-west-2': '433757028032.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-1': '811284229777.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'us-east-2': '825641698319.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest',
              'eu-west-1': '685385470294.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xgboost:latest'}

hyperparameters = {
        "max_depth":"5",
        "eta":"0.2",
        "gamma":"4",
        "min_child_weight":"6",
        "subsample":"0.7",
        "objective":"binary:logistic",
        "num_round":50
        }

estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(image_name=containers['us-east-1'], 
                                          hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                                          role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                                          train_instance_count=1, 
                                          train_instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge', 
                                          train_volume_size=5, # 5 GB 
                                          output_path=output_path,
                                          train_use_spot_instances=True,
                                          train_max_run=300,
                                          train_max_wait=600)
```

However, running the following throws an error:

```
estimator.fit({'train': s3_input_train,'validation': s3_input_test})
```

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: Invalid DNS suffix 'amazonaws.com' for region 'us-east-1' in training image. Please provide the valid <region>.<dns-suffix>: 'ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Can someone help on how to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the region with boto3.session.Session().region_name?

Comment: The notebook instance was created in ap-south-1 and the S3 bucket was in us-east-1. Creating another notebook instance from the same region as the S3 bucket resolved the issue. How would I access S3 from a different region?

Comment: Since S3 is global, it doesn't make a difference from where you access S3.

Comment: But the error vanished the moment I created another notebook instance in the same region (without any other changes). Is there any S3 setting I have to change in order to access it from other regions?

Comment: No, because the problem is not the S3 bucket. The bucket doesn't have a region. The problem was that your container was in another region. Sagemaker is pulling the image from ECR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notebook instance was created in ap-south-1 and the S3 bucket was in us-east-1. Creating another notebook instance from the same region as the S3 bucket resolved the issue.